# Do not have all privileges of a postgres database in psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I trying to write a python function to add some data into database.

```py
from psycopg2 import connect

username = "username"
pswd = "1234"
db_name = "project_db"
con = connect(user = username,
                      password = pswd,
                      host = "127.0.0.1",
                      port = "5432",
                      database = db_name )  
cursor = con.cursor()
query = "INSERT INTO test_(name) "\
        "VALUES ('my_name')"

cursor.execute(query)
```

the result is :`psycopg2.errors.InsufficientPrivilege: permission denied for table test_` .
I tried grant all privileges to my user using this command:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE project_db to username;
```

and then restarted the database, but the result is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Granting privileges on database does neither grant privileges on database schemas nor on objects in schemas.

You need to grant privileges on schema and schema objects with specific GRANT statements.

See [Privileges section in PG docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-priv.html).